# Intuition behind using a monotonic stack

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-subarray-minimums/):

> Given an array of integers A, find the sum of min(B), where B ranges over every (contiguous) subarray of A.  Since the answer may be large, return the answer modulo 10^9 + 7.
>   
>   
>   **Input**: [3,1,2,4]
>   **Output**: 17
>   **Explanation**: Subarrays are [3], [1], [2], [4], [3,1], [1,2], [2,4], [3,1,2], [1,2,4], [3,1,2,4]. Minimums are 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1.  Sum is 17.

A [highly upvoted solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-subarray-minimums/discuss/178876/stack-solution-with-very-detailed-explanation-step-by-step) is as below:

```
class Solution {
public:
  int sumSubarrayMins(vector<int>& A) {
    stack<pair<int, int>> in_stk_p, in_stk_n;
    // left is for the distance to previous less element
    // right is for the distance to next less element
    vector<int> left(A.size()), right(A.size());

    //initialize
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) left[i] =  i + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) right[i] = A.size() - i;

    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
      // for previous less
      while(!in_stk_p.empty() && in_stk_p.top().first > A[i]) in_stk_p.pop();
      left[i] = in_stk_p.empty()? i + 1: i - in_stk_p.top().second;
      in_stk_p.push({A[i],i});

      // for next less
      while(!in_stk_n.empty() && in_stk_n.top().first > A[i]){
        auto x = in_stk_n.top();in_stk_n.pop();
        right[x.second] = i - x.second;
      }
      in_stk_n.push({A[i], i});
    }

    int ans = 0, mod = 1e9 +7;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
      ans = (ans + A[i]*left[i]*right[i])%mod;
    }
    return ans;
  }
};
```

My question is: what is the intuition behind using a monotonically increasing stack for this? How does it help calculate the minimums in the various subarrays?

Comment: The stacks aren't monotone increasing, I can see two pops in the code, one for each.

Comment: A 'monotone' stack, by which I presume you can only mean 'monotonically increasing', is a contradiction in terms. The moment you pop from it, it decreases. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421, I think my main question is not whether we should call it `monotone` stack or `monotonically increasing` stack - it is more about why a stack is being used in the first place.  How does it help us achieve what we are seeking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visualize the array as a line graph, with (local) minima as valleys.  Each value is relevant for a **range** that extends from just after the previous smaller value (if any) to just before the next smaller value (if any).  (Even a value larger than its neighbors matters when considering the singleton subarray that contains it.)  The variables `left` and `right` track that range.

Recognizing that a value **shadows** every value larger than it in each direction separately, the stack maintains a list of previous, unshadowed minima for two purposes: identifying how far back a new small number’s range extends and (at the same time) how far forward the invalidated minima’s ranges extend.  The code uses a separate stack for each purpose, but there’s no need: each has the **same** contents after every iteration of the (outer) loop.

Comment: Okay, it makes more sense to me now.  Also, what is the formula `ans + A[i]*left[i]*right[i]`?  Could you please elaborate on that please?

Comment: @J.Doe: That’s how many subarrays include that element (as a minimum): the number of places to start it times the number to end it.

Comment: for formula `ans + A[i]*left[i]*right[i]` [check the explanation here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GyygvrTJ3GY/XRlvmDTxEHI/AAAAAAAAO4E/yDc-Xvo3isgM8QFOSiVp6yUK_j9E8cwGACK8BGAs/s0/2019-06-30.jpg)

Comment: Could you add an example please? I was a little unsure if the values that the answer refers to are the values in the stack or in the input array. There are simpler examples like https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/description/.

Comment: @ashkan117: An example of what?  The code is already in the question.  The values in the stack are (some of) the values from the input array, so it's "both".

Comment: I was trying to apply your explanation to the following example [73,74,75,71,69,72,76,73]. "Each value is relevant for a range that extends from just after the previous smaller value (if any) to just before the next smaller value". So if the value is index 1 which has value 74 that range would be index 0 till index 3?

Essentially if possible applying your observations to a similar example for added clarity